# maven create two jars one for src/main code and other for src/test

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have two sub folders:

1. src/main/scala
2. src/test/scla

I want to create two jars out of it. Can you please help me with the maven `pom.xml` to create the two jars.

Note: I am beginner in maven.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>Pricing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>  

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

with this it is creating two jars one containing all the code and the other having test code ...my requirement is to have main code one and test code other...not to mix...please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [test-jar goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) of the jar plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tdrury... I would try to set testOutputDir in the scala plugin to a different folder so test classes and main classes are generated in different folders. Then using the `test-jar` goal in the `maven-jar-plugin` configure the `testClassesDirectory` property accordingly.